# Tensorflow 2 Image Batch Prediction Return Results

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

I have an already trained model and I want to make binary classification predictions on images in a directory. I have over 100,000 images so for efficiency, I want to do batch predictions. How can I do batch predictions on my images, get the prediction results, and store the images in two separate folders after they have been predicted on based on the class?

This is what my code looks like so far...

```
model_filepath = r"C:\Users\model_200.h5"
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_filepath)

test_dir = r"C:\Users\image_testing_folder"

batch_size = 64
IMG_HEIGHT = 200
IMG_WIDTH = 200

test_image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_image_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=str(test_dir),
                                                         batch_size=batch_size,
                                                         shuffle=False,
                                                         target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                         )

predictions = (model.predict(test_image_gen) > 0.5).astype("int32")
predictions
```

One solution would be to tie the prediction with an image filepath, then use shutil.move() to move original image to a destination folder. How would I do this? Is there a better way to do batch predictions than using an ImageDataGenerator and .flow_from_directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a custom dataset so you can also easily retrieve the filename:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from glob2 import glob
from shutil import copy
import numpy as np

files = glob('group1\\*\\*.jpg')

imsize = 64

def load(file_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, size=(imsize, imsize))
    return img, file_path

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files).\
    take(100).\
    shuffle(100).\
    map(load).batch(4)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), input_shape=(imsize, imsize, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.build(input_shape=(imsize, imsize, 3))

categories = np.array(['cats', 'dogs'])

target_dir = 'newpics'

for cat in categories:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(target_dir, cat), exist_ok=True)

for images, filenames in ds:
    preds = model(images)
    targets = categories[np.argmax(preds, axis=1)]
    for file, destination in zip(filenames, targets):
        copy(file.numpy().decode(), os.path.join(target_dir, destination,
                                os.path.basename(file.numpy().decode())
                                ))
        print(file.numpy().decode(), '-->', os.path.join(target_dir, destination,
                                os.path.basename(file.numpy().decode())
                                ))
```

```
group1\cats\cat.4051.jpg --> newpics\cats\cat.4051.jpg
group1\cats\cat.4091.jpg --> newpics\dogs\cat.4091.jpg
group1\cats\cat.4055.jpg --> newpics\cats\cat.4055.jpg
group1\cats\cat.4041.jpg --> newpics\cats\cat.4041.jpg
group1\cats\cat.4090.jpg --> newpics\cats\cat.4090.jpg
group1\cats\cat.4071.jpg --> newpics\dogs\cat.4071.jpg
group1\cats\cat.4082.jpg --> newpics\cats\cat.4082.jpg
group1\cats\cat.4037.jpg --> newpics\cats\cat.4037.jpg
group1\cats\cat.4005.jpg --> newpics\cats\cat.4005.jpg
```

All you have to change is the glob pattern and folders.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response!

Comment: One question though; Although you've created a custom dataset with 100 images per "batch", you use a for-loop to iterate through each image. Is your solution a true "batch prediction" in the sense of generating predictions for a set of images "all at once"? 
How does it compare in terms of prediction speed to a solution like model.predict_classes(np.vstack(test_images_2)) or using a TF ImageDataGenerator? Perhaps the for-loop is necessary to return filepaths tho. Thanks!

Comment: For the first one, you would need to load all images in memory, which is most likely to overload memory. For the second, it's the same, because ImageDataGenerator uses my implementation under the hood. As you can see above, it uses a batch size of 4 so more than one samples are predicted at once. So it is indeed faster. You can even pump up this number. You can use batch size 256 if it fits in memory.